# Docker port forwarding using localhost

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a memcached service running on port 11211 in a docker container and I want to access this service from within another container using 127.0.0.1:11211. Im using docker-compose and nothing of "links", "ports" or "expose" seems to work for me. I don't wanna have to access with the ip of the memcached docker container instead I want to access it as it were a local service of the other container. Is there any solution?

Thanks!

```
version: '2'
services:
  memcached:
    build: ./memcached
    image: memcached_img
    expose:
      - "11211"
  web:
    build: .
    image: app:latest
    mem_limit: 512m
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    command: [ "script/startup.sh", "web" ]
  worker:
    build: .
    image: app:latest
    mem_limit: 512m
    command: [ "script/startup.sh", "worker" ]
```

Comment: Can you post your compose file to provide a more clear answer?

Comment: I added the file, so basically I want to access the service memcached from the web service.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to change Memcache conf to allow to connect with other hosts

```
 go to /etc/memcached.conf:
 change -l 127.0.0.1 to -l 0.0.0.0 # or simply comment it out
```

build image.

in your docker-compose file

```
services:
  memcache:
    ports:
      - host_port: docker_service_port
```

Comment: For me it seems like you make the service available to the host. then I would have to call from the "web" service the host_ip:11211. But my "web" service calls memcached on localhost:11211.

Comment: @charly1212, you can  create links and tell your web service to connect to link_name:link_port

Comment: I was already playing around with links but had no luck. I added links: - "memcached:11211" under web. Is that right?

Comment: @charly1212, first update the memcache conf, then web conf, build, create links, run

Comment: I got it working now, basically I did the memchached.conf and the links. Nevertheless it's not what I wanted, because for that I also had to change the memcahed client to call the service with the hostname instead of localhost. For me it seems one cannot share services between different docker containers as they were native on localhost.

Comment: @charly1212, remember, there is no place like localhost. if both services are running in different containers, then you can not use localhost.

Answer (score 1):

Create [docker network](https://docs.docker.com/network/#network-drivers) to communicate between containers

```
version: '2'
services:
  memcached:
    build: ./memcached
    image: memcached_img
    expose:
      - "11211"
    networks:
      - web-network
  web:
    build: .
    image: app:latest
    mem_limit: 512m
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    command: [ "script/startup.sh", "web" ]
    networks:
      - web-network
  worker:
    build: .
    image: app:latest
    mem_limit: 512m
    command: [ "script/startup.sh", "worker" ]
networks:
   web-network:
      driver: bridge
```

Now you can "access" services using their names. E.g. you can access memcached service from web service using `memcached:11211` as **host:port**

Comment: Thank you but actually as I described I don't want to access it as a hostname or ip instead I want to access it as it were on localhost or 127.0.0.1. For me it seems it is not working that way thats why I changed my web service which is a client for memcached to call memcached with the hostname.

Answer (score 0):

You can whether use 'expose XXXX' in Dockerfile, or use -p when running the container for the 1st time.
It will be super helpful for us to help you if you provide your Dockerfile that built your image from.

Answer (score 0):

localhost inside the container is a different isolated network. Not the host's localhost.

You could add `depends_on: memcached` to the web container. This will add the `memcached` host to the `web` container and you will be able to ping that host from there. Docker will take care of port forwarding. It will also make sure to start web only once memcached has already started. You could then `telnet memcached 11211` from within `web`.

Comment: Please note that I'm not too familiar with the memcached internals but it sounds like your issue can be fixed just from the docker context

Comment: I did depends_on: \n -memcached under web, but doing netstat inside web, I still don't see a 11211 running :/

Comment: what do you mean actually with fixing just form docker context?

Comment: If you do a `docker ps` you'll see that the memcached port is exposed and you should be able to access it. By "docker context " I meant that you should be able to make it work by changing docker configuration

Comment: Docker ps shows 11211/tcp  but netstat in web container shows no listening on 11211. also netstat on host shows no 11211